# Top vertical align on inline element in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, inline, vertical-alignment

I like to align an inline element to the top of other enclosing inline elements.

That's my code:

```
<style>
  span {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
</style>
<span><a><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" /></a></span>
<span><a><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/50" /></a></span>
```

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqNpZ/)

For some reason Safari (Mac-Version) can't handle this code, it aligns the images to the bottom. :(

Does anyone know what's the problem or even how to solve it? Welcome are all solutions using pure HTML and CSS **without changing the display-property** of any element mentioned above.

The last restriction is the tough part. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly it wasn't working in any browsers.

Use [**`vertical-align`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) on the `img` as opposed to the parent, `span`. This is the correct usage of the property.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7wTSj/)

```
span img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and useful answer! I like to give you a +1, but I'm not allowed to.